# Reducing Vertex Cover to Half Vertex Cover

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, vertex-cover, polynomial-time-reductions

I need to reduce Vertex Cover to Half Vertex Cover using a Karp reduction:

Vertex Cover: Given a graph $G = (V,E)$ and an integer $k$, is there a subset of $V$ of size $k$ which intersects all edges?

Half Vertex Cover: Given a graph $G = (V,E)$ and an integer $k$, is there a subset of $V$ of size $k$ which intersects exactly half the edges?

I will be happy if you can tell me how to do that and why the reduction works (both directions of the proof).

Comment: We're not here to do your homework!

Comment: However, in this case it seems that the exercise is not straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Let *special vertex cover* be the special case of vertex cover in which $|V| = 2k+1$. We later reduce vertex cover to special vertex cover.

Now suppose we're given an instance $G = (V,E),k$ of special vertex cover. Construct an instance $G',k$ of half vertex cover by attaching $|E|$ new edges to each vertex in $V$.

The total number of edges in the new graph is $|E|(|V| + 1)$. A vertex cover of size $k$ in the original graph covers this many edges in the new graph:
$$
|E|(1+k) = |E|\left(1 + \frac{|V|-1}{2}\right) = |E| \frac{|V| + 1}{2},
$$
exactly half the edges. Conversely, consider any $k$ vertices of the new graph, which cover exactly half of the edges. If they cover $m$ of the original edges then they cover at most $m + k|E|$ edges of $G'$, where $m \leq |E|$. The calculation above shows that $m = |E|$, that is, all edges of $G$ are covered.

It remains to reduce vertex cover to its special case. If $|V| = 2k+1$ then there is nothing to do.

If $|V| < 2k+1$, then we add $\delta := 2k+1 - |V|$ many paths of length 2 edges. The new graph $G'=(V',E')$ has a vertex cover of size $k' = k + \delta$ iff the original graph had a vertex cover of size $k$. Note that
$$
|V'|-2k' = (|V| + 3\delta) - 2(k+\delta) = |V| - 2k + \delta = 1.
$$

Similarly, if $|V| > 2k+1$ then we add $\delta := |V| - (2k+1)$ many triangles. The new graph $G'=(V',E')$ has a vertex cover of size $k' = k + 2\delta$ iff the original graph had a vertex cover of size $k$. Note that
$$
|V'|-2k' = (|V| + 3\delta) - 2(k+2\delta) = |V| - 2k - \delta = 1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the reduction given by Yuval Filmus, you can also use the following reduction, which avoids blowing up the size of $G$ to $\Theta(|V| \cdot |E|)$.

Assume w.l.o.g. that $k<|V|$ (otherwise the reduction is trivial) and that the instance (graph) $G = (V,E)$ of vertex-cover contains a vertex $v \in V$ of degree $1$ (otherwise you could append a path of length $2$ to any vertex and increase $k$ by $1$).

To obtain an instance $G'$ of half-cover attach to $v$ $|E|$ new edges (towards new nodes), so that $G'$ has $2|E|$ edges.

If there is a vertex cover of size $k$ in $G$, then there is also a vertex cover $C$ of size $k$ that does not include $v$. Then, $C$ intersects $|E|$ edges in both $G$ and $G'$, i.e., half the edges of $G'$.

On the converse, if there is a half-cover $C'$ of size $k$ for $G'$ then $v \not\in C$ (since the degree of $v$ is $|E|+1$), and hence $C' \subseteq V$ covers all $\frac{2|E|}{2} = |E|$ edges in $E$.